# Post data on web server with web service

Tags: objective-c, json, web-services, ios5

Hello I am tying to save data on web server with a web service implemented in PHP.

I am trying below code to do it. I am getting response from server but the data is not getting saved to server. I have wasted 5-6 hours of the day in googling and trying code given on net. But nothing seems to work :(

```
NSDictionary *someInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      txtTreasureName.text, @"name",
                                      txtDescription.text, @"description",
                                      txtMaterials.text, @"materials",
                                      @"77.3833", @"longitude",
                                      @"29.0167", @"latitude",
                                        categoryIdStr, @"categoryId",
                                      nil];

        NSError *error;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:treasureInfo
                                                        options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted 
                                                            error:&error];    

        if (! jsonData) {

            DLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);

        } else {
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];        
        NSString *urlString = @"http://www.myurl.php";

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];        
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        [request setValue:@"application/json"
    forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        [request setValue:@"application/json"
    forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",
                           [jsonData length]]
       forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];

        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];


        DLog(@"%@", request);

        [[NSURLConnection alloc]
         initWithRequest:request
         delegate:self];


        // Print json
        DLog(@"JSON summary: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];            
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                                      queue:queue
                                          completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                                              NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                                              if ([data length] &&
                                                  error == nil) {

                                                  DLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                                                  if ([self shouldDismiss]) {

                                                      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                                               completion:nil];

                                                  }

                                              }                                             
                                          }];      

    }
```

Comment: What is the error message? What is the line? What language is that?

Comment: I am not getting any error. I am getting response from server but data is not just getting saved on server.

Comment: So the data is getting to the server but not being saved by the server ?

Comment: As an suggestion, I strongly advice to take a look on [RestKit](http://www.restkit.org), this framework makes really easy to serialize data to json and configure the calls to your webservice methods.

Comment: put your server side PHP script as well to review what you are doing there.

Comment: @Wain you got it exactly. Call to server is being made but some how server is not treating it as a valid post request

Comment: So we really need to see the server setup because your code above looks ok. I agree with @ararog about using RestKit to make life easier but I don't think the app code is your problem. Does the server actually accept JSON body data? If not then the answer from @'Dipen Panchasara' s a good bet.

Comment: @Wain you are right the problem is solved now. Problem was with server  side code. Thank you everybody for your time, quick responses and help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Request URL in the function,
You have alread y created data Dictionary

```
NSDictionary *someInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          txtTreasureName.text, @"name",
                          txtDescription.text, @"description",
                          txtMaterials.text, @"materials",
                          @"77.3833", @"longitude",
                          @"29.0167", @"latitude",
                          categoryIdStr, @"categoryId",
                          nil];
```

Add this function to your implementation file and invoke it, rest will be dont by this function

```
[self postWith:someInfo];
```

Add this

```
- (void)postWith:(NSDictionary *)post_vars
{
#warning Add your Webservice URL here
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YourHostString"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSString *boundary = @"----1010101010";

    //  define content type and add Body Boundry
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [post_vars keyEnumerator];
    NSString *key;
    NSString *value;
    NSString *content_disposition;

    while ((key = (NSString *)[enumerator nextObject])) {
        value = (NSString *)[post_vars objectForKey:key];

        content_disposition = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key];
        [body appendData:[content_disposition dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];        
    }

    //Close the request body with Boundry
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", body.length] forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Length"];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);        
}
```

Comment: This could be an appropriate answer for the question how to send a multipart form request. However, as it looks like, this won't work since the server apparently expects application/json as content type. The OP should be more specific about what errors are returned and what the server expects.